# Maven changelog plugin with Mercurial problem

Tags: maven-2, mercurial, changelog

I have configured my Maven2 project to generate a changelog report from a Mercurial repository (accessible via file:// protocol) but the goal execution fails with the following message:

```
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'changelog'.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Phobos3 Prototype
[INFO]    task-segment: [changelog:changelog]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [changelog:changelog {execution: default-cli}]
[INFO] Generating changed sets xml to: D:\Documents and Settings\501845922\Workspace\phobos3.prototype\target\changelog.xml
[INFO] EXECUTING: hg log --verbose
[WARNING] Could not figure out: abort: Invalid argument
[ERROR]
EXECUTION FAILED
  Execution of cmd : log failed with exit code: -1.
  Working directory was:
    D:\Documents and Settings\501845922\Workspace\phobos3.prototype
  Your Hg installation seems to be valid and complete.
    Hg version: 1.4.3+20100201 (OK)


[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR]
EXECUTION FAILED
  Execution of cmd : log failed with exit code: -1.
  Working directory was:
    D:\Documents and Settings\501845922\Workspace\phobos3.prototype
  Your Hg installation seems to be valid and complete.
    Hg version: 1.4.3+20100201 (OK)


[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] An error has occurred in Change Log report generation.

Embedded error: An error has occurred during changelog command :
Command failed.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: An error has occurred in Change Log report generation.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An error has occurred in Change Log report generation.
        at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:79)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.reporting.MavenReportException: An error has occurred during changelog command :
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.changelog.ChangeLogReport.generateChangeSetsFromSCM(ChangeLogReport.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.changelog.ChangeLogReport.getChangedSets(ChangeLogReport.java:393)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.changelog.ChangeLogReport.executeReport(ChangeLogReport.java:340)
        at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:98)
        at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.execute(AbstractMavenReport.java:73)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Command failed.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.changelog.ChangeLogReport.checkResult(ChangeLogReport.java:705)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.changelog.ChangeLogReport.generateChangeSetsFromSCM(ChangeLogReport.java:467)
        ... 23 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Apr 29 17:10:06 CEST 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/10M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What did I miss in a configuration? (I hope it is a configuration problem not a Maven plugins related bug!:) My repository URL seems to be ok (the plugin has been complaining before, I fixed that up), I also set a date format for parsing (also been complaining, also fixed).

target/changelog.xml being promised was not generated at all.

Maven 2.2.1
Mercurial 1.4.3
Windows XP SP3

`mvn scm:changelog` command provides an expected output.

Thanks for any suggestions, I haven't googled up anything (nor binged up;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a test with a random project ([noop](http://code.google.com/p/noop/), to be precise):

```
hg clone https://noop.googlecode.com/hg/ noop
```

And after configuring the [`dateFormat`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-changelog-plugin/changelog-mojo.html#dateFormat) of the `maven-changelog-plugin` in the top `pom.xml`:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-changelog-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <dateFormat>EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy Z</dateFormat>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I've been able to run `mvn changelog:changelog` without troubles. My point is that the plugin seems to work for at least one project (chosen randomly :).

I'd really like to know if `hg log --verbose` behave correctly as the plugin seems to complain about it not running successfully. If it does, could you try to pass the `-X` option when running Maven and see if you get more useful information.

Also, please provide the content of your `<scm>` element.